# Use the SVM classifier instead of Softmax in the caffe CNN architecture

Tags: deep-learning, svm, caffe, convolution, softmax

I want to use the SVM Classifier instead of Softmax in a caffe CNN architecture.

How to do it and what should I change the `deploy.prototxt` and `train_val.prototxt` in the last layer?

In `deploy` for the last layer I have:

```
layer {
    name: "loss"
    type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
    bottom: "fc8"
    bottom: "label"
    top: "loss"
}
```

In `train_val` for the last layer I have:

```
layer {
    name: "loss"
    type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
    bottom: "fc8"
    bottom: "label"
    top: "loss"
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want to do; an SVM classifier takes a vector of input observations -- raw data -- and returns the category of the region in which that data point falls.  This is a trained SVM model.  `SoftMax` takes a vector of classification scores and normalizes them to probabilities; it is part of the training process.  The two work on the same data format, but on distinct applications.  If you have a usable SVM to classify your input, you don't need a CNN at all.

Comment: It's very clear. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Prune SVM classifier is perfectly applicable as a final layer for classification. It doesn't return probabilities, but rather hinge loss of each class. It can be backpropagated and in practice, SVM and Softmax are usually comparable. Here you can find the details: http://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/#svm So it's absolutely clear what this question is about.

Answer (score 1):

The term *SVM* is usually associated with an [independent method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) used for binary classification. That's why there's no *such* layer in Caffe. What you are really looking for is [Hinge loss](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers/hingeloss.html). Example:

```
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "HingeLoss"
  bottom: "fc8"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
  hinge_loss_param {
    norm: L2
  }
}
```

A [complete example](https://github.com/abhi-kumar/Caffe-Python-Basic-Tutorial/blob/master/hingelossLayer_example.prototxt) for MNIST classification.